# JQuery validate plugin - success callback misfires

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am validating a dynamic form (rules come from the server for each field) using the JQuery validate plugin. For some reason the `success` callback is being called on all fields regardless of the real outcome.

The form itself IS validated correctly and will not submit if there are errors.
The problem is thus a display one: the success callback is responsible for removing the red error indicator and showing a green check sign, and so the indication to the user contradicts the real outcome.

This used to work it the past, but I can't detect any change that would cause such an issue.

```
        var form = $(form);
        var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
        var success = $('.alert-success', form);
        var rules = Subject.getRules(Subject.rulesWithMimes);

        form.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            rules:rules,
            messages:messages,
            ignore:'[type=file]',
            debug:false,
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit  
                success.hide();
                error.show();

            },
             onkeyup: function(el, e) {
            this.element(el);

             },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type

                var icon = $(element).parents('.input-icon');
                if (!icon.length) {
                  var name = $(element).prop("name");
                  icon = $('.datePicker[data-question='+name+']');
                }


                icon = icon.find('i.tooltips');

                icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");  
                icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({'container': 'body'});
            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs


            var el=Subject.findValidationElement(element);

                el.removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
                el.find("i.tooltips").removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check").trigger("mouseenter");


            },

            unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

                el = $(element).closest("td");
                el.removeClass("has-error")
                          .addClass('has-success'); 

                           el.find("i.tooltips").removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check").attr("data-original-title","");
            },

            success: function (label, element) {

             console.log("success");
                var el = $(element).parents('.input-icon').closest(".form-group,td");
                if (!el.length) {
                var name = $(element).prop("name");

                el = $(".datePicker[data-question="+name+"]");

              }

              if ($(element).parents('.radio-table').length) {
                el = $(element).parents("tr");
              }
                var icon = el.find('i.tooltips');
                el.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
                icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
                 icon.trigger("mouseleave");
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {

               if (!UploadFile.areRequiredFilesUploaded()) {
                bootbox.alert(trans('validation.requiredFiles'));
                return false;

               }

                success.show();
                error.hide();
                if (AppData.studyId!=AppData.demoStudyId)
                form.submit(); // submit the form
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code - judging by your self-answer, the key code is not included above (i.e. the contents of the messages variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the I've passed a messages array with some `null` properties. Apparently the plug-in doesn't alert anything, even in `debug` mode, and presents the behavior described in my question for those fields where the message was `null`.

Answer (score 2):

submitHandler is where you put code to deal with the successful submit of the form.

The [success](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) option is called every time an individual input is valid.

Quote from the docs:

> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If
>   a String is given, it is added as a class to the label. If a Function
>   is given, it is called with the label (as a jQuery object) and the
>   validated input (as a DOM element). The label can be used to add a
>   text like "ok!".

So, it sounds like it's doing exactly what it's supposed to in the case where some elements are valid, and some are not.

Comment: I agree.  It's also a very ambiguously written question.

Comment: I've removed all validation rules but one, and still the success callback fires both on change and on submit. As before, the form itself is not submitted when the field is not valid

Comment: Sounds like it's working as it should then.  Every time an element is validated and found to be valid, the success callback will be called.  Being called twice on submit is probably less than ideal in terms of efficiency, but shouldn't cause you any real problems.

Comment: I think it's actually not being called on submit, it's being called by change and blur events

Comment: It's called both on change and on submit, and in my case even if there is only one field to validate and the field is invalid.